# Error while updating column with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

While updating the column I am getting exception message:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

```
UPDATE item_t0   SET
item_t0.p_enddate=DATEADD(day, 10, item_t0.p_enddate)
FROM employee item_t0
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT '1' FROM
orders item_t2 ON  item_t2.p_id  =  item_t0.p_subsid  JOIN 
departs item_t4 ON  item_t4.PK = item_t0.p_contract  JOIN 
constantvalues3b item_t1 ON  item_t0.p_status  =  item_t1.PK   
WHERE 
 item_t0.p_startdate  > 'Aug 10, 2020 12:00:00 AM' and  item_t0.p_enddate  < 'Sep 10, 2020 12:00:00 AM'
                 AND  item_t1.Code  in('Active')
                 AND  item_t0.p_planid ='asdcg'
                AND item_t0.customer='1234567'
                 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be trying to join your sub-query to the parent query which isn't possible in this format. Instead move it to part of the where clause.

NOTE: I highly recommend taking the time to layout your queries in a neat logical fashion - much easier to debug.

```
UPDATE item_t0 SET
    item_t0.p_enddate = DATEADD(day, 10, item_t0.p_enddate)
FROM employee item_t0
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT '1'
    FROM orders item_t2
    -- Move to where clause
    -- ON  item_t2.p_id  =  item_t0.p_subsid
    JOIN departs item_t4 ON item_t4.PK = item_t0.p_contract
    JOIN constantvalues3b item_t1 ON item_t0.p_status = item_t1.PK   
    WHERE item_t0.p_startdate > 'Aug 10, 2020 12:00:00 AM' and item_t0.p_enddate < 'Sep 10, 2020 12:00:00 AM'
    AND item_t1.Code in ('Active')
    AND item_t0.p_planid = 'asdcg'
    AND item_t0.customer = '1234567'

    -- Moved fdrom attemped join
    AND item_t2.p_id  =  item_t0.p_subsid
)
```